Ubuntu 22 not getting ip from dhcp on boot
We have a network with ISC running and serious number of VMs running in the same network. While this specific Ubuntu is booting it does not get IP from DHCP. According to DHCP logs, ISC is giving the IP without any problem and even it gets a DHCPACK. However server boots with no IP.
Log from the dhcp;
Dec 17 01:56:38 template dhcpd[684]: DHCPDISCOVER from 66:a9:3f:9c:77:9d via eth0
Dec 17 01:56:38 template dhcpd[684]: DHCPOFFER on ##### IP ##### to 66:a9:3f:9c:77:9d via eth0
Dec 17 01:56:38 template dhcpd[684]: DHCPREQUEST for ##### IP ##### (##### DHCP IP #####) from 66:a9:3f:9c:77:9d via eth0
Dec 17 01:56:38 template dhcpd[684]: DHCPACK on ##### IP ##### to 66:a9:3f:9c:77:9d via eth0

The interesting part is when we login to server and run "dhclient", it does get the related IP address.
What do you think the cause would be ?

Read DHCP client logs. Probably, journalctl and whatever. // Funny to notice, you're hidden IP address, which I bet are private and nothing is wrong with sharing it, that absolutely can not hurt you in any way. My computer has 192.168.160.166, how much it says about me? Nothing. Same thing is with NIC names: everybody has the same. Whereas, MAC addresses can theoretically be used to track or identify you, so if there was something to be hidden, that's these, but they're not hidden. In practice, however, don't hide that either.

Could it be that your server has other network config software which immediately removes the newly-configured IP address? Please look through the system boot logs (the entire journalctl -b).

@NikitaKipriyanov Thanks for the comment. This happens only on boot and I could not catch any logs, but definitely will look next time. About the IP; I have my own reasons.

@grawity I thought about that too and checked. I found another DHCP as you stated and shutdown that too. But it continued to happen after that too. I will check this again when I encounter this problem again.
